# why iPhone .app files is much larger than .ipa file?

Tags: iphone, xcode, app-store

My new iPhone application have .ipa file size (by Archive) is 2.8 MB, which is okay.
But my .app file is much large > 13 MB, and AppStore describes my app's size is 7.9 MB.

What causes this problem? Can I make my app size in AppStore is the same as my ipa file?

Thanks,

UPDATE:

- When I unzip .ipa file, I see an .app file whose size is 5.2 MB!!!. It seem that I have difference configuration between these build settings. Wonder if I can use this app file to upload (beta tester can use this anyway!)
- When I use iTunes to sync my downloaded app from AppStore, the .ipa size is > 13M (same as my uploaded .app)

Comment: When showing my .app content, I found that the biggest file is my binary, the image and sounds file do not have any significant change. So, I tried to reduce number of included source files in project, update framework, remove unused one. The compiled .app reduced nearly a half. I'm waiting for Apple reported size when they updated my app.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

.ipa files are compressed, which explains why they're smaller. I'm not sure why your .app file is so much larger than what the App Store reports unless Apple does some sort of image compression for the App Store.

Comment: Image compression is done when you compile the application.  As far as I know Apple doesn't touch the images when they put it on the store.  They might compress the app when they send it to the device, which'll explain the difference.

Comment: I also think the compress the app when sending it to device. That explains why appstore description size is less than the .app file.

Answer (score 4):

Right-click on the .app file in your build folder and "Show Package Contents" and see what images and other files were included in the build.  You can look at the sizes of everything in there.

Comment: I see my Binary app file is largest. The sounds and images does not change much.

Answer (score 0):

How large a .app directory is reported to be on a Mac depends on the HD drive formatting and/or disk block size quantization.  The sum of the raw (unpadded) data byte sizes can be smaller, and the compressed archive size even smaller yet.

Comment: Dear @hotpaw2 , please explain your answer + provide a reference.

Comment: If the minimum disk allocation block for a file is 4k, then a 1 byte file might be reported as 4k on that particular hard disk.  100 of these files would take up 400kB.  But much much smaller when archived in a format that does require as much padding around just 100 bytes (plus file info).  See Apples HFS format docs.